# How to I trigger a jQuery .on('click', selector, callback) event from JSDOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jsdom

I have a piece of code that sets up my event handlers:

```
const element = $('#my-element');
const menuToggle = '.menu-toggle';
function assignEventHandlers() {
  element.on('click', menuToggle, handleMenuClicked);
}
```

In JSDOM, I want to trigger that click event for a mocha unit test. 
I can select the element `.menu-toggle` in JSDOM, but if I go to trigger it like this, `$('.menu-toggle').trigger('click');` the callback `handleMenuClicked` function does not get called.

How can I trigger this event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM Api and dispatch an event externally using `dispatchEvent()`

In your case, the code could look something like this :

```
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
$('.menu-toggle')[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

I'm not sure how jQuery has this implemented, but I've came accross this and seen this working on jsdom

Comment: I have tried that, but when I replace window with my jsdom window variable, I get an error that says MouseEvent is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: @cjh193 What is your jsdom version ?

Comment: jsdom version 11.2.0